# чтение из файла txt

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Добрый вечер,

пошагово проверяю программу и обнаружил, что неправильно считываются входные данные их файлов txt. Вот часть кода:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h> 

using namespace std;

double Tnach[139][139][50];
double Temper[139][139][50];
double Temper1[139][139][50];
double Tempernach[139][139][50];
double Tut[139][139];
double Tut1[139][139];
double Tut11[139][139];
double Tut22[139][139];

int main() {
const int i = 0;
```

дальше много перечислено переменных, участвующих в расчете, потом продолжение кода, где мне нужно считать из трех файлов .txt значения, из которых потом сформировать массивы и использовать в расчетах:

```
ifstream fan1;
fan1.open("pov20.txt", ios::in);
ifstream fan2;
fan2.open("nak20.txt", ios::in);
ifstream fan3;
fan3.open("h20.txt", ios::in);
ofstream fout;
fout.open("res1.txt", ofstream::out);

for (int i = 0;i<Lan;i++) {
    for (int j = 0;j<Lan;j++) {
        fin1 >> pov[i][j];
        fin2 >> nak[i][j];
        fin3 >> h[i][j];
    }
}
```

По поводу этого при сборке выдается ошибка сборки, а в выходных данных из сборки пишется: 
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Project1, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>c:\users\л\source\repos\project1\project1\source.cpp(78): error C2296: >>: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "double"
1>c:\users\л\source\repos\project1\project1\source.cpp(78): error C2297: >>: недопустимо, правый оператор имеет тип "double"
1>c:\users\л\source\repos\project1\project1\source.cpp(79): error C2296: >>: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "double"
1>c:\users\л\source\repos\project1\project1\source.cpp(79): error C2297: >>: недопустимо, правый оператор имеет тип "double"
1>c:\users\л\source\repos\project1\project1\source.cpp(80): error C2296: >>: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "double"
1>c:\users\л\source\repos\project1\project1\source.cpp(80): error C2297: >>: недопустимо, правый оператор имеет тип "double"
1>Сборка проекта "Project1.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========

То есть если я понимаю правильно, ему не нравится тип fin1? fin2 и fin3. Но они на самом деле действительные, тут никак не получается иначе.
Как мне считать данные из файлов чтобы использовать их в расчетах?

Comment: что то мне кажется, что внутри цикла должны быть fan1, fan2, fan3, а не fin1, fin2, fin3

Comment: Что такое `fan` `fin` `pov` `nak` `Lan`?  Вам следует начать давать осмысленные имена, тогда многие нестыковки сразу начнут бросаться в глаза.